# Play a sound immediately with QT Phonon (not waiting for event loop)

Tags: c++, qt, phonon

I am playing sound for user interactions in C++ using QT's Phonon component. After a lot of testing I can confirm that a queued sound will only start playing when the main thread returns to the main message loop. For long processing code this introduces a delay in sound playback. I need to find a way to avoid that delay.

I've tried doing the sound in a separate thread, but a [defect](http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-15948) in Phonon prevents some of the objects from being created in that thread. Thus some signals are always stuck in the main thread.

Simply returning to the event loop quickly is not an option for a few reasons:

1. Some object creations is simply slow and can't be sped up or easily done in a thread (like database connections)
2. Phonon uses multiple signals, so even if you return quickly other signals/events will nonetheless block/interfere with the phonon signals

I'm just looking to cover the most basic use case for a sound API: play a sound when a user does something (like click a button) and have that sound play immediately. Surely that must be covered somehow in Phonon?

Comment: you could try calling `QApplication::processEvents` right after the sound playback has been issued...

Comment: Point #2 still means you can't fix it by calling processEvents -- unless somebody can provide a filter for just Phonon events/signals.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked if phonon in qt 4.7 has been improved but I considered using it for a similar purpose (in qt 4.6) and rejected it because it could not play/mix two sounds at the same time. I did not even get to any run time testing. I went with SDL Audio, specifically [SDL Mixer](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/) it has low latency on playing and you can play multiple sounds at the same time.

Comment: I need a cross-platform solution (Linux/Windows/more). Also my needs are very limited thus I don't wish to learn a more advanced library (if I can avoid it).  BTW, Phonon can play multiple sounds at the same time.

Comment: @edA it's pretty much as thin as you can get, you will probably use about 10 calls if even. I had it wrapped in a very thin class, and yes as Mihai said it SDL is as cross platform as you can get

Comment: Okay, once I got to the main page http://www.libsdl.org/ it is quite clear that is cross-platform. I'll have to look at it.